# Rails - API Restfull - Allow only GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have an API with user authentication and I want to deny the access to POST/PUT/DELETE for clients users (only admin users can do it).

1 - How can I set this?

2 - Where do I have to put these rules if I want to use them in the entire application?

Comment: @Acacia gave you the answer. Learn to use cancan and insert it into your app.

Comment: Thank you all, I'll try and post the results soon.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem. This way in your authorization folder you define that unless user is "admin" then cannot :create, :update or :delete User.

It looks like this in `app/models/ability.rb`

```
def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
       if user.role == "admin"
         can :manage, :all
       else
         can :read, :all        
         cannot [:create, :update, :destroy], User         
       end
  end
```

Then in the controller creating Users, just add `authorize_resource`

Comment: This is a very good option as well. I used it on a project but forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you put it in the routes file, where books would be your model to which you want to deny update/delete access to your users. You can namespace the api for admin users to allow access. I use this approach in a lot of my code successfully.

```
resources :books, except: :update, :delete


namespace "admin" do
  resources :books
end
```

Comment: But in this case it will deny for all users correct? And I need block only for common users.

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect that using namespace in routes file.